# Ruby Metaprogramming: creating a method by a method

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming

I just wondered about some metaprogramming.

Actually I need to create a method within a method, or just create a method in the root of a class by a block. example:

```
["method_a", "method_b"].each do |m|
  Marshal.generate_a_method_called(m)
end
```

Does somebody know how this is possible? And where to place what the method does? I need one argument for my method.

Yours,

Joern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use define_method:

```
[:method_a, :method_b].each do |m|
  define_method(m) do
    # your method stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your example. Are you generating the source for the method as well?

So I will start with an example from the book [Perrotta: Metaprogramming Ruby](http://www.amazon.de/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476)

```
class MyClass
  define_method :my_method do |my_arg|
    my_arg * 3
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.my_method(2) # => 6
```